# Java getJSONArray when it is set to null

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

The problem happens when I'm trying to get children of a comment. If the child key is null, my application crashes and gives me this error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value null at child of type
> org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
 if (comments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("child") != null) {child = comments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("child");
```

What should I do?

Comment: comments.getJSONObject(i).get("child") != null should work I guess or you can simply use child = comments.getJSONObject(i).optJSONArray("child")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (comments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("child")
```

Replace

```
if(comments.isNull(comments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("child")));
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, i think you should confirm that with your backed, define witch field can be null or not.
- Second, if all field can be null, you can use more powerful lib for decode json information, like `[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)`, it can help you deal the null fields without exception.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).